# Change "Sign in" text size

Tags: android, xml

I am using g+ login in my app. I want to customize the g+login button. How to increase size of text "g+ sign" in button.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="info.taramt.com.tmtsars.MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/android">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tmtlogo" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"


    >
</com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>
```

Comment: Edit google's code in the library.

Comment: You have to change it programmatically in the library.

Comment: how can i change i think it is in jar file

Comment: Ya i found the SignInButton.class but i can't change it is showing source not found

Comment: You have to download the project and use it as a library.